# How to achieve loading large data in table component with pagination, filtering, sorting capabilities with angular 6

Tags: angular, user-interface

I am an amateur angular developer and working on a requirement where i need to load > 1 million records on table with pagination. How can i handle pagination, sorting and filtering on the complete set of data. Also, How can i lazy load the dataset, also make sure the sorting, filtering is happening on the complete data and not just a chunk of data. 
1. Is it possible to achieve this with any libraries, I need some working demos or a guide to implement this.

Comment: I suggest use a component like this: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Answer (score 0):

There are frameworks like angular material or primeng that providence table with pagination.
But I'm notre sure for the lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned here is not a problem at all. Its the basic functionality of any data grid. You have plenty of options to look in to.

1. [PrimeNg table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) (Turbo table also known as p table): Ease of development, but very slow if you use formatting and have records over 150 per page. Good documentation, free.
2. [Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/): Has community and priced version. Good documentation. Performance is also better. Development is harder than the PrimeNg table but not that considerably difficult. Supports animations as well.

When you consider performance over everything else 1st option which I've mentioned won't be even in a list. Hence depend on your requirement choose the perfect grid. Here are some high performance grids which shines above all but doesn't have good documentation or tutorials even. But in performance wise it'll outshine both I've mentioned above.

3. Fin-Hypergrid. [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fin-hypergrid), [github](https://github.com/fin-hypergrid/core), [CDN](https://fin-hypergrid.github.io/), [API doc](https://fin-hypergrid.github.io/core/3.2.0/doc/Hypergrid.html), [demo](https://fin-hypergrid.github.io/core/3.2.0/)
4. SlickGrid. [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-slickgrid), [github](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki), [demo](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/basic)

For better performance comparison please refer this [article](http://www.crankuptheamps.com/blog/posts/2017/10/05/grid-comparison/).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Per company policy, I have access to use Primeng and ngx-bootstrap. How will I handle such huge data on UI ? Will we call API on every sort or filter or pagination ?

Comment: @SNaik In short yes you will have to make call every time for filtering and pagination. Bringing huge data is very costly and hit your performance as well as rendering will take time.  At first show some data in grid and later based on filter and sort event you can fetch data again from backend. As per my experience Primeng is good option and very easy to implement

Comment: @SNaik refer to my answer's links. `PrimeNg` table has your each and every requirement fulfilled, but will be performing very slow if you have to work over 150 records (rows) per page when you were doing pagination. How ToDos are there with the documentation with the tutorials if you are going through with it. (Not recommending for large data sets)

Comment: How do we implement the API from UI and backend ? Is there a demo I can refer to ? If I'm calling API on every event like sort, filter , paginate  - how is Primeng making my life easy ? If Primeng framework is handling everything, how should the backend be designed and how can we design the API to keep a continuous connection to get data in UI?